# How to understand the the sum expression, sum(A14+A15:A19)

Tags: google-sheets

I write a wrong expression sum(A14+A15:A19). Actually the right way for me is A14+sum(A15:A19). Curiously, the former can run as well with no error.  So I spent much time to check the adequate result and find the odd phenomenon.

[image]

Besides, when I input the expression in the row 20,21 , error appears.  Is that a bug? What's the meaning?

Thanks.

Comment: It's a weird way to use unnamed ranges. I don’t even think it's planned to work. Similar question here: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/66824/element-wise-operations-on-cell-ranges-in-google-spreadsheet

Comment: @Germán  It indeed run. You can try~

Comment: Yes I know. What I mean to say is that it shouldn't.

Answer (score -1):

The `sum` function takes in parameters separated by `,`s (not `+`s).

It's a little counterintuitive, since you're trying to add things together, but instead of `=sum(A14+A15:A19)` try `= sum(A14,A15:A19)`.

All that being said, I assume there's a reason why you wouldn't simplify the whole thing and use `=sum(A14:A19)`.

Comment: Thanks Nick. I have already known my mistake. Here I am curious the meaning of sum(A14+A15:A19). Why It can evaluate?